# React.js inifinite loop in useEffect if I try to remove the warning

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

The only way I have gotten my code to work, produces a warning. If I try to fix the warnings, it sends the useEffect into an infinite loop. It is because I am updating state in the useEffect like so... How can I fix this to work without warnings?

```
const CombineRemainderData = (props) => {

    const {remainderData, setAllHistoricalData, allHistoricalData, devices} = props
    useEffect(() => {
        // doing stuff then setting state like below. I left out this and denoted it as newState below.
        setAllHistoricalData({...allHistoricalData, newState: newState, keys: devices})
    }, [remainderData, setAllHistoricalData, devices])
}
```

the warning asks to add "allHistoricalData" to the dependency array but this leads to an infinite loops for obvious reasons. How can I remove this warning the correct way?

Comment: It is defined in a parent component, aka another js fil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a callback function in your state setter:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setAllHistoricalData(allHistoricalData => ({
    ...allHistoricalData, 
    newState: newState, 
    keys: devices
  }));
}, [remainderData, setAllHistoricalData, devices])
```

Comment: OMG this is exactly it. I just don't understand why but I can research. Using data => ...data is the way to go. Thank you

Comment: I edited for a bit of clarity. You can pass the `setAllHistoricalData` function another function that takes the current data as an argument

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // other code
    ...
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
```